# Why does \notblank still believe its argument not be blank, even after expansion?

Tags: expansion, etoolbox

In the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\@mkCommands}{mm}{%
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname @#1\endcsname{}{%
    \notblank{#2}{%
      NO \MakeUppercase{#2} PROVIDED,
      USE \textbackslash #1 COMMAND%
    }{}%
  }
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1\endcsname{m}{%
    \expandafter\RenewDocumentCommand\csname @#1\endcsname{}{##1}%
  }
}

\@mkCommands{testCmdA}{TEST-COMMAND-A}
\@mkCommands{testCmdB}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\makePage}{}{%
  A: \@testCmdA

  \protected@edef\@tempa{\@testCmdB}%
  \expandafter\notblank\expandafter{\@tempa}{%
    B: \@testCmdB
  }{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makePage

\end{document}
```

The intended output should be:

```
A: NO TEST COMMAND A PROVIDED, USE \testCmdA COMMAND
```

However, the actual output is:

```
A: NO TEST COMMAND A PROVIDED, USE \testCmdA COMMAND
B:
```

In other words, `\notblank` believes `\@tempa` not to be blank, even though it should fully expand `\@testCmdB` which *should* be blank.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Expanding `\@tempa` once gives merely `\@testCmdB`.  Expanding it twice gives `\__xparse_start_expandable:nNNNNn {}\@testCmdB \@testCmdB \@tes-
tCmdB code ?{}`.  So it is not empty.  Try `\detokenize\expandafter{\@tempa}
\par
\detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\@tempa}` after you define it and you will see.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Hm, any idea on how to work around this problem? I presume expanding it twice (or thrice, ...) is not going to make it work as intended?

Comment: No it will not.

Comment: The other macros from `etoolbox` to test voidness are much better to use in this case. For example `\ifdefvoid`

Comment: erh, what is this code even suppose to do?

Comment: @daleif It is part of a class that provides a set of commands for providing information when typesetting the title page and copyright page. If some information is not set then it should warn about it.

Comment: @gablin I use a simular approach in our corporate letter design. In the colophon I test holder macros, if they do not exist, or are empty (including white space), they are not printed. I use `\ifdefvoid` and `\ifcsvoid` for this. The issue here is the `\ifnotblank` in `\makePage`, `\ifdefvoid` might help there, I just cannot figure out what is going on inside the last part of the definition of `\@mkCommands`

Comment: why do you need to test? If you make (say) the default definition of `\@title` be `\error{title not provided)` and provide a command `\title` that defines `\@title` then if the user supplies no title an error will be given when the title page uses `\@title`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There are some fields that are not mandatory, and these I want to test.

Comment: @daleif That is indeed the problem. After reading your comment, I rewrote my class to test for `\ifcsdef` and then added a `\@ifHasField` command for checking whether the field has been set or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define `\@testcmdB` with `\NewDocumentCommand`, it is a `\protected` macro, so it remains untouched in an `\edef` (and `\protected@edef` as well).

I think a different approach is better and that `\NewDocumentCommand` here is more of a hindrance than help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\@mkCommands}[2]{%
  \ifblank{#2}
    {\@namedef{@#1}{}}
    {%
     \@namedef{@#1}{%
       NO \MakeUppercase{#2} PROVIDED,
       USE \texttt{\symbol{`\\}#1} COMMAND%
     }%
    }%
  \@namedef{#1}##1{%
    \global\@namedef{@#1}{##1}%
  }%
}


\@mkCommands{testcmdA}{test-command-A}
\@mkCommands{testcmdB}{}

\newcommand{\makePage}{%
  A: \@testcmdA
  \expandafter\notblank\expandafter{\@testcmdB}{%
    \\
    B: \@testcmdB
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{No commands given}

\makePage

\section{Command A}

\testcmdA{Here is a test}

\makePage

\section{Command B}

\testcmdB{Here is b test}

\makePage

\end{document}
```

[image]

A rather different approach. I provide instead of several commands, a interface with `\@useCommand` which takes two arguments: the command name (such as `testcmdA`) and the action to be performed with the contents of the related token list, denoted by `#1` (or `##1` if inside a definition, of course).

If `\@mkCommands` is used with a trailing optional argument, the defined command is considered mandatory for the user, so the warning about providing it in the document appears when `\makePage` is executed. Otherwise it's not considered mandatory and `\@useCommand` will do nothing with the specification if the related contents is still empty.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \g_gablin_makepage_commands_clist

\NewDocumentCommand{\@mkCommands}{mo}
 {
  \tl_new:c { g_gablin_makepage_#1_tl }
  \IfValueT { #2 }
   {
    \clist_gput_right:Nn \g_gablin_makepage_commands_clist { #1 }
    \tl_gset:cn { g_gablin_makepage_#1_tl }
     {
      NO ~ \tl_upper_case:n { #2 } ~ PROVIDED, ~
      USE ~ \texttt{\symbol{`\\}#1} ~ COMMAND
     }
   }
  \exp_args:Nc \NewDocumentCommand { #1 } { m }
   {
    \tl_gset:cn { g_gablin_makepage_#1_tl } { ##1 }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\@useCommand}{mm}
 {
  \cs_set:Nn \__gablin_makepage_do:n { #2 }
  \clist_if_in:NnTF \g_gablin_makepage_commands_clist { #1 }
   {
    \__gablin_makepage_do:v { g_gablin_makepage_#1_tl }
   }
   {
    \tl_if_blank:vF { g_gablin_makepage_#1_tl }
     {
      \__gablin_makepage_do:v { g_gablin_makepage_#1_tl }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__gablin_makepage_do:n {}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__gablin_makepage_do:n { v }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_blank:nF { v }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\@mkCommands{testcmdA}[test-command-A]
\@mkCommands{testcmdB}

\newcommand{\makePage}{%
  \@useCommand{testcmdA}{%
    A: ##1
  }%
  \@useCommand{testcmdB}{
    \\
    B: ##1
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{No commands given}

\makePage

\section{Command A}

\testcmdA{Here is a test}

\makePage

\section{Command B}

\testcmdB{Here is b test}

\makePage

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as before.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

The problem is that `\NewDocumentCommand` does not expand to simple text.  If you want to test something as blank, you have to make sure it expands to simple text, namely in this case, blank text.  So, for the case you want to test, you need to use a `\def` rather than a `\NewDocumentCommand`.

I place, in the definition `\@mkCommands` the `\notblank{#2}` outside the definition of `\@#1`.  If it is blank, I use a simple `\def` to define `\@#1` as `{}`.  That way, in the later `\@tempa` test, the `\notblank` will detect a blank `\@testCmdB`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\@mkCommands}{mm}{%
  \notblank{#2}{%
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname @#1\endcsname{}{%
      NO \MakeUppercase{#2} PROVIDED,
      USE \textbackslash #1 COMMAND%
    }}%
  {\expandafter\def\csname @#1\endcsname{}}%
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1\endcsname{m}{%
    \expandafter\RenewDocumentCommand\csname @#1\endcsname{}{##1}%
  }
}

\@mkCommands{testCmdA}{TEST-COMMAND-A}
\@mkCommands{testCmdB}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\makePage}{}{%
  A: \@testCmdA

  \protected@edef\@tempa{\@testCmdB}%
  \expandafter\notblank\expandafter{\@tempa}{%
    B: \@testCmdB
  }{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makePage

\end{document}
```

Comment: But why even define the holder macro? `\ifdefvoid` returns true if the macro does not exist.

Comment: @daleif I just work here. (which is to say, I am too incompetent to understand your question)